# how to increase bottom border for navigation bar in bootstrap with CSS

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

basically, i want to add colored border below navigation bar (default fixed navbar) in bootstrap. For that i have added border style in CSS and it's working which shows border below navigation bar but i want this border somewhat thicker and i am not getting how to do this?
Code-

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>HOME</h3>
    <p>home</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <p>home1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <p>home2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 3</h3>
    <p>home3</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and CSS as below

```
.navbar-default{
background-color: #A52A2A !important;
border-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 15px;
border-bottom-color: #7FFF00 !important;
}
```

but here this border-bottom-width: 15px; property not going to work....
so is there any option to increase thickness of border? if u have any other solution then also suggest me....thank u

Comment: Can you show us in which order you called your bootstrap.css and your own main.css?

Comment: thanks Johannes to pint out this, due to my mistake i was placed my CSS file right above bootstrap.css, which creates problem....now i corrected it and it's working fine...

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers. Also please read [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) on accepting answers and `thank you` comments.

Answer (score 1):

.navbar-default
{border-bottom: 15px solid #7FFF00 !important;
background-color: #A52A2A !important; }

Try with this

Answer (score 0):

use for example 2px after border-style: solid;

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you encounter may be due to the fact that your css file is above the bootstrap.css file. This results in the fact that **bootstrap.css overwrites your custom CSS**, hence not giving a wider border-bottom. You can resolve this problem by putting your custom CSS under the bootstrap.css file, giving you the *last word* on the styling.